# Convert datetime to string in expression builder SSIS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-data-tools

I encountered a strange problem, moving from VS2015 to 2019. I've got a variable that is setup like this;

```
 SUBSTRING( (DT_STR,50, 1256)DATEADD("DAY",0,GETDATE()) , 1, 10)
```

This works perfectly in VS2015 but now when I tried to add the same code in a project, it returns "Cannot convert 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'."

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use c#

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This link has all versions:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: Yes, but not in the expression builder.

Comment: It's a pain in the butt to write that out in an expression. That's why I gave you a simple script task to do it. You need to date part the heck out of getdate() to do it in an expression.

Comment: ok, but the fact remains, why does it work perfectly in VS2015 and not in VS2019...

Comment: @KeithL, how do you parse it in a script expression to use as a variable in Expression Builder?